# Random: ConnectException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Tags: ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Webservice has been developed in `ASP.NET`

We use `KSOAP2` in Android App. Now, **SOMETIMES** App gets Error like mentioned above.

Both Server and Clients are in same network environment. As the error is generated at **RANDOM** I am not able to track down the cause for it.

**TRIED:**

1. Networks checks / Reachability checks / telnet and pings to server.
2. Devices / Emulators on same and different networks.
3. 3G / EDGE / WiFi Connectivity on Devices.
4. Server has been allocated maximum bandwidth (Also, only one device is using it right now.)

**NOTE:** All the possible combination of above points has been tried for number of times.

Can anyone advice me on how can I trace it ? (The main problem is it's random)

Also, Any thoughts on whether it's on `server side` or `client side`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should check that your **KSOAP2 calling** runs in separate `Thread`.

Then you should set up proper value for timeout.

```
HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE(host, port, file, timeout);
```

It is random exception, so it is difficult find the reason. Probably your server has sometimes the delay. But it is usual problem. You should make handling the exception for correct running app. In this case, make new calling to your web service.